# Batch file for restarting print spooler deletes desktop icons, anyone?

Tags: windows-7, printing, batch-file

Can anyone explain what has happened here?

If this is ran on a machine on our domain without elevating it to admin, it deletes all desktop icons. I'm at a loss as to how or why?

```
@echo off
net stop spooler
IF NOT exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd echo NO DOCUMENTS IN QUEUE ONCE THE SPOOLER HAS STARTED TRY PRINTING AGAIN
IF NOT exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd msg * NO DOCUMENTS IN QUEUE ONCE THE SPOOLER HAS STARTED TRY PRINTING AGAIN
IF exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd
IF exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.spl del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.spl echo PRINTER QUE CLEARED PLEASE TRY PRINTING AGAIN msg * PRINTER QUE CLEARED PLEASE TRY PRINTING AGAIN
net start spooler
pause
```

Any advice would be gratefully appreciated as it's caused a slightly major problem this morning and I'm in need of an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your commands aren't being combined as you intend.  Everything after `del` is being deleted -- most notably the line just before `net start spooler` which contains a spurious asterisk.  So essentially you are calling `del *`, which deletes everything in the current working directory (ostensibly, your Desktop).

If you want multiple commands to be issued as a result of a matched `if` condition, use parentheses and new lines.

```
@echo off
net stop spooler
IF NOT exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd (
    echo NO DOCUMENTS IN QUEUE ONCE THE SPOOLER HAS STARTED TRY PRINTING AGAIN
    msg * NO DOCUMENTS IN QUEUE ONCE THE SPOOLER HAS STARTED TRY PRINTING AGAIN
) else (
    del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.shd
)
IF exist C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.spl (
    del C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS\*.spl
    echo PRINTER QUE CLEARED PLEASE TRY PRINTING AGAIN
    msg * PRINTER QUE CLEARED PLEASE TRY PRINTING AGAIN
)
net start spooler
echo Press any key to exit.
pause>NUL
```

Comment: @rojo Thank you, I shall pass this on fortwith!

Comment: So basically treat it like a full grown program and structure it :)